# Link to specific page on Google Document Viewer on iPad

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ipad, pdf, iframe

I am thinking of using the Google Document Viewer to show PDF files that are hosted by our company server.

The scenario is:

1. A webpage will contain a menu with menu items that are actually different pages of a PDF file.
2. After clicking a menu item, that particular page from the pdf will be displayed on that same web page
3. This project is targeted for mobile devices (iPad, for now)

Now, I am using an iFrame like below:

```
    <iframe id="iframe1" width="100%" height="800px" src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://cb.vu/unixtoolbox.pdf&embedded=true"></iframe>
```

But I don't know if linking to a specific page is possible or Google would like that because I tried the solutions posted on [how to open specific page on Google's docs viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193144/how-to-open-specific-page-on-googles-docs-viewer?answertab=votes#tab-top) and http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2009/11/link-to-page-in-googles-document-viewer.html but all of them seem to be outdated.

Is this even possible? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible by doing something like the following:

```
http://somepdf.pdf&a=bi&pagenumber=xx
```

It's strange that it is nowhere documented.

Comment: ...toolbox.pdf&embedded=true&pagenumber=15 doesn't work. How did you use the pagenumber with the iframe and google src? I think this is a adobe plugin parameter.

Comment: a=bi is vital. Did you try toolbox.pdf&a=bi&pagenumber=15 instead?

Comment: No I'll try it with a=bi and report back later