# Asp.net MVC4, Mobile Safari, iFrame - add link to each page of a multi-page pdf document

Tags: pdf, iframe, asp.net-mvc-4, mobile-safari

While http://www.example.com/my.pdf#pageX works on the iPad to open the page "X", this does not work while the pdf is embedded in an iFrame. Has any of you has a solution how to link to a specific page of a pdf document in an iFrame on the iPad, or a similar solution that will show a specific page of a pdf document within an html page?

I have been looking for a solution for months now and have not come across the solution yet. Tried google doc viewer and tried to go to a specific page using almost all the solutions posted on the web (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290148/link-to-specific-page-on-google-document-viewer-on-ipad) but those solutions seem dated and do not work.

Any help is appreciated.