# How can I change an IFRAME location.hash value without the parent jumping down to the IFRAME?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm successfully changed the hash value for the location of an IFRAME ([as a part of externalizing navigation through Google Document Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9228965/866618)), however I can't figure out how to stop the parent jumping down to the top of the IFRAME when the function is triggered.

Does anyone have a JS/jQuery solution? I've found [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5651372/866618) (also below), but the solution seems dirty and prone to be problematic. Thoughts?

```
var yScroll=document.body.scrollTop;
window.location.hash = id;
document.body.scrollTop=yScroll;
```

Also, for reference, the function I'm using is this:

```
function st_go_to_pg( pg ){
    if( pg >= 0) jQuery('.gde-frame').first()[0].contentWindow.location.hash=':0.page.'+pg;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like no one has a better solution that what I included in the initial question, I suppose I'll just post that as the answer.

The resulting function to change pages within the document embedded while not changing the y scroll location of the parent page is as follows:

```
function go_to_pg( pg ){
    var y=document.body.scrollTop; // save parent y to undo jump to top of IFRAME
    if( pg >= 0) jQuery('.gde-frame').first()[0].contentWindow.location.hash=':0.page.'+pg;
    document.body.scrollTop=y; // reset y
}
```