# Google drive embedded PDF preview JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, html, google-docs

## Context

### If you have a google drive pdf file

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m2CvxFDRpoZCKT9yBhKj835_aIa7SwXd/preview

### you can use iframe

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/
1F3onzGtFoYpcVxow7gq4BbeL0zbZhxuf/preview" \>
```

### iframe preview

[image]

## Problem

- How to navigate
- to specific page
- from the parent page
- using js

## Why

- because I have an html table with some reference to specific pages
- I want the page visitor to view a page when he click the table entry
- I want the file to be hosted on google drive if possible

### Similar questions but not working

- this one using **Google's docs viewer** not  **google drive**

  - [pdf - how to open specific page on Google's docs viewer - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193144/how-to-open-specific-page-on-googles-docs-viewer)

Comment: The solution to this must involve something besides an iframe because javascript has limited access to an `iframe`.

After this is answered, I'd also like to see if the proposed solution supports private drive files. The `iframe` only works for public files.