# how to display docx files in brower and navigate to specific page in browser using js and html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I want to achieve this following scenario. When I click on a button, doc(x) file(using remote url) should display 3rd page in the web browser. I tried with google doc viewer and ms doc viewer. I am able to view the file but I can't navigated to the specific page automatically. Every time showing first page of the Document. I did not found any solution. Kindly help me out. I struck for 2 days.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Duplicate of [how to open specific page on Google's docs viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193144/how-to-open-specific-page-on-googles-docs-viewer).